# why svmpredict in LIBSVM returns empty prediction and accuracy?

Tags: matlab, libsvm

so my code is

```
% using LIBSVM   '-t 0' means linear '-c 0.1' means C = 0.1
model = svmtrain(y, X , '-t 0 -c 0.1');

% using LIBSVM 
[p, accuracy] = svmpredict(y, X, model);
```

but I get empty results for "p" and "accuracy" variables.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853267/matlab-libsvm-unable-to-predict) question in the stack exchange and that does not answer my problem .

EDIT

so my problem is solved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305425/why-am-i-getting-an-empty-matrix-from-svmpredict) question.

But I still don't understand why the matlab command

```
[p, accuracy] = svmpredict(y, X, model);
```

is inccorect . since I have even tested with a simple function my self I know that in matlab if our function let's say "fun" returns two values like

```
function [ minus , plus ] = fun( a , b )

  minus = a-b;

  plus = a+b;

end
```

now if I use this function as

```
[m ] = fun(1,2)
```

matlab will answer -1 . instead of returning a null answer like "svmtrain".

Why is this happening ?

Comment: note that `svmtrain` is also a MATLAB function. Make sure you are not mixing LIBSVM with MATLAB

Comment: no , that's not the case if you have your own specific  function in the active directory your function is whats being used. BUT if found the answer I should use the return statement as [p , accuracy , ~] !  found it in this thread   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305425/why-am-i-getting-an-empty-matrix-from-svmpredict